# What do I have to install or modify to fix the CS1543, Visual Studio 2015 error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I copied a project from one computer to another computer, normally I used the get and set with this syntax

```
public decimal Total { get => total; set => total = value; }
```

But when I pass it to the other computer, I get the error cs1543 in many lines, should I install something so that the code is evaluated correctly?

Comment: Make sure your project is targeting the correct .net framework that supports expression bodies in properties

Comment: Have you tried closing Visual Studio, deleting `.vs` folder from the root of your project and then opening the project again?

Comment: @MarkoPapic Yes, that I tried and the error persists.

Comment: @SyntaxError What version do you support? Currently it is with Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Expression bodied properties require C# v7.0, first released in VS2017.